# how can i use input from a text box to change part of an iframe url?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color:#ffffff
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- im attempting to make an iframe display a video the user types into 
the prompt.-->
<input id="txtUrl" style="width:82%;" placeholder="youtube.com/watch?v=(finish the url)" name="url" type="text" />

<iframe src="www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/(I WANT THE USERS INPUT 
HERE)" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got this far and my mind is going blank. every time i think of a possible solution, it just leaves my mind and i'm back to confusion. This is probably really easy to fix and i'm just stupid, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `src` attribute of an iframe. Try doing that on `keyup` event. Then you can see the change immediately.

```
var textField = document.getElementById('txtUrl');

textField.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src', textField.value);
})
```

I haven't tested the code but you should get the basic idea on how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get input's value and then add this value to iframe's `src` attribute (add to existing value). Here is solution (if anything isn't clear - feel free to ask):

```js
function changeSrc() {
  const elem = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
  const inputVal = document.getElementById("txtUrl").value;
  elem.src += inputVal
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<input id="txtUrl" style="width:82%;" placeholder="youtube.com/watch?v=(finish the url)" name="url" type="text" />
<button onclick="changeSrc()">Change src</button>
<iframe src="www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: where would i put the JavaScript? i put it at the beginning of the <body> in <script> tags and it didn't work. the answer is probably really obvious, but i haven't messed with any code for over a year. im trying to re-teach myself.

Comment: @Useless when script does something with DOM, the DOM should be rendered before the interpreter will reach this lines, so you have to put `script` tag right before the `</body>` closing tag

Comment: i just tried that and unfortunately, it is not working for me. :( i had a site like this (but working) a long time ago, but my school deleted all my files from my laptop.